# C# where I went wrong

Tags: c#

This is an exercise I already submmited and I'd like to better understand where I went wrong. The program should calculate how many candy we get to eat and how many wraps are left, given there's a promotion where for X amount of wraps we get Y free candy and then we can use those wraps to get an additional amount of free candy till we don't reach the amount required to get more.

My solution works for several cases but not for some, as in:

For 4 Wraps get 2 Freebies, Buy 8 = 13 Eaten and 5 WrapLeft (should be 14 Eaten and 2 WrapsLeft).

I have read the code lots of times and can't figure out if I designed the formulas badly or is it a coding mistake (although it compiles ok). I'm stucked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace candy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Wrap = 0;
            int Freebie = 0;
            int TotalFreebie = 0;
            int Buy = 0;
            int Increment = 0;
            int Eaten = 0;
            int WrapsLeft = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Introduce amount of wraps");
            Wrap = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce number of freebies per wrap");
            Freebie = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce amount of candy bought");
            Buy = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            TotalFreebie = (Buy / Wrap) * Freebie;
            Eaten = Buy + TotalFreebie;
            WrapsLeft = Eaten - Buy;

            if (Freebie > Buy || Freebie >= Wrap)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("COMPANY GOES BANKRUPT");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                if (TotalFreebie > Wrap)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        TotalFreebie = (Buy / Wrap) * Freebie;
                        Increment = TotalFreebie / Wrap;
                        Increment++;
                        Eaten = Buy + TotalFreebie + Increment;
                        WrapsLeft = Eaten - (Buy + TotalFreebie);

                    } while (TotalFreebie > Wrap);
                }

                else 
                {
                    if (TotalFreebie == Wrap && Buy > Wrap)
                    {
                        TotalFreebie = (Buy / Wrap) * Freebie;
                        Eaten = Buy + TotalFreebie + Freebie;
                        WrapsLeft = Eaten - (Buy + TotalFreebie);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        TotalFreebie = (Buy / Wrap) * Freebie;
                        Eaten = Buy + TotalFreebie;
                        WrapsLeft = Eaten - Buy;
                    }
                }

                TotalFreebie = (Buy / Wrap) * Freebie;
                Eaten = Buy + TotalFreebie + (TotalFreebie / Wrap);

                if (TotalFreebie > Wrap)
                {
                    WrapsLeft = Eaten - (Buy + TotalFreebie);
                }

                else
                {
                    WrapsLeft = Eaten - Buy;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Eaten, WrapsLeft);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: yes but I still don't understand a lot of it, we are still starting on Visual Studio from pseudocode.

Comment: I still can't get my head around your question. I'm a little confused. But, what I think you're saying is you buy a certain amount of candies, for example, 8, and you can trade in 4 wraps from eaten candies for 2 more candies, and you can keep doing this until you run out of wraps. And what you need is how many candies you can get in total for the original number of candies, and how many wrappers will be left after the trading. Is this correct?

Comment: Exactly, "Eaten"·is "number of candies consumed in the end (bought + total of freebies" and WrapLeft is "amount of wrappers left after I exchange the wrappers from the candies bought AND the wrappers of the Freebies that I can also use to get X amount of freebies for Y amount of wrappers".

Comment: Your code has some errors in it.  Where is the variable Compro defined?  Also you misspelled a Frebie.

Comment: "Compro" = "Buy". The code is translated from spanish. That also accounts for the mispelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show you where it all went wrong... See the flow if the user input matches the scenario you mentioned...

```
//For 4 Wraps get 2 Freebies, Buy 8 = 13 Eaten and 5 WrapLeft (should be 14 Eaten and 2 WrapsLeft).
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int Wrap = 0;
    int Freebie = 0;
    int TotalFreebie = 0;
    int Buy = 0;
    int Increment = 0;
    int Eaten = 0;
    int WrapsLeft = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Introduce amount of wraps");
    Wrap = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // 4
    Console.WriteLine("Introduce number of freebies per wrap");
    Freebie = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // 2
    Console.WriteLine("Introduce amount of candy bought");
    Buy = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // 8

    TotalFreebie = (Buy / Wrap) * Freebie; // 8/4*2 = 4
    Eaten = Buy + TotalFreebie; // 8+4 = 12
    WrapsLeft = Eaten - Buy; 12-8 = 4

    if (Freebie > Buy || Freebie >= Wrap) // 2 > 8 || 2 >= 4 *FALSE*
    {
        Console.WriteLine("COMPANY GOES BANKRUPT");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    else
    {
        if (TotalFreebie > Wrap) // 4 > 4 *TRUE*
        {
            do
            {
                TotalFreebie = (Buy / Wrap) * Freebie;
                Increment = TotalFreebie / Wrap;
                Increment++;
                Eaten = Buy + TotalFreebie + Increment;
                WrapsLeft = Eaten - (Buy + TotalFreebie);

            } while (TotalFreebie > Wrap);
        }

        else 
        {
            if (TotalFreebie == Wrap && Buy > Wrap) // 4 == 4 && 8 > 4 *TRUE*
            {
                TotalFreebie = (Buy / Wrap) * Frebie; // 8/4*2 = 4
                Eaten = Buy + TotalFreebie + Freebie; // 8+4+2 = 14
                WrapsLeft = Eaten - (Buy + TotalFreebie); // 14-(8+4) = 2
            }

            else 
            {
                TotalFreebie = (Buy / Wrap) * Freebie;
                Eaten = Buy + TotalFreebie;
                WrapsLeft = Eaten - Buy;
            }
        }

        TotalFreebie = (Buy / Wrap) * Freebie; // 8/4*2 = 4
        Eaten = Buy + TotalFreebie + (TotalFreebie/Wrap); // 8+4+(4/4) = 13 

        if (TotalFreebie>Wrap) // 4>4 *FALSE*
        {
            WrapsLeft = Eaten - (Buy + TotalFreebie);
        }

        else
        {
            WrapsLeft = Eaten - Buy; // 13-8 = 5 
        }



        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Eaten, WrapsLeft); // 13 5
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here's a modified version... Since I removed a bit of code you might want to verify if the error handling you initially still applies or not..

```
//For 4 Wraps get 2 Freebies, Buy 8 = 13 Eaten and 5 WrapLeft (should be 14 Eaten and 2 WrapsLeft).
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int Wrap = 0;
    int Freebie = 0;
    int TotalFreebie = 0;
    int Buy = 0;
    int Increment = 0;
    int Eaten = 0;
    int WrapsLeft = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Introduce amount of wraps");
    Wrap = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // 4
    Console.WriteLine("Introduce number of freebies per wrap");
    Freebie = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // 2
    Console.WriteLine("Introduce amount of candy bought");
    Buy = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // 8


    if (Freebie > Buy || Freebie >= Wrap) // 2 > 8 || 2 >= 4 *FALSE*
    {
        Console.WriteLine("COMPANY GOES BANKRUPT");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    else
    {
        TotalFreebie = (Buy/Wrap)*Freebie; // (8/4)*2 = 4

        WrapsLeft = Buy%Wrap + TotalFreebie; = 8%4 + 4 = 0+4 = 4

        while(WrapsLeft >= Wrap) // 4>=4 *TRUE* // 2>=4 *FALSE*
        {
            TotalFreebie += (WrapsLeft/Wrap)*Freebie; // 4 + (4/4)*2 = 4 + 2 = 6
            WrapsLeft = (WrapsLeft/Wrap)*Freebie; // (4/4)*2 = 2
        }            

        Eaten = Buy + TotalFreebie; // 8+6 = 14

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Eaten, WrapsLeft); // 14 2
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest there's so many redundant logic that it makes no sense anymore.. I suggest re-designing the program if you want to try again..

Comment: Ok... The light went on, thank you!!! So the problem is I had defined the IF conditionals very badly and I should have been more specific defining every IF. The case where it results 13 should have been also defined as an if with its conditionals, and the WrapsLeft variable should have been defined under every main IF.

Comment: I thought the same, I got so stucked at writing the code that past certain point I wasn't even thinking clearly. I'll redesign to see if this time I'm capable of doing it right. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me see it!

Comment: I edited and added a working one which might help you figure out the problem

Comment: Wow thanks! I'll try it with other numbers too and see how it works and if I need to add something else, but you showed me the right path, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few issues with your code.

The three variables that you set using `Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` are only ever set once. They don't change throughout the code after the initial input. So, look at this loop:

```
        do
        {
            TotalFreebie = (Buy_SETONCE / Wrap_SETONCE) * Freebie_SETONCE;
            Increment = TotalFreebie / Wrap_SETONCE;
            Increment++;
            Eaten = Buy_SETONCE + TotalFreebie + Increment;
            WrapsLeft = Eaten - (Buy_SETONCE + TotalFreebie);
        } while (TotalFreebie > Wrap_SETONCE);
```

You'll see the variable that are set once because I renamed then with `_SETONCE` appended to their names. You'll see that through each iteration of the loop that `TotalFreebie` will be a constant value since it is only made from values that are set once. So that means that if `TotalFreebie > Wrap_SETONCE` is `true` then you'll never ever leave the loop.

If you don't enter the loop then you hit the other side of the `if` which will set `TotalFreebie`, `Eaten`, & `WrapsLeft`, but immediately after this code runs those three variables are set again:

```
    TotalFreebie = (Buy_SETONCE / Wrap_SETONCE) * Freebie_SETONCE;
    Eaten = Buy_SETONCE + TotalFreebie + (TotalFreebie / Wrap_SETONCE);

    if (TotalFreebie > Wrap_SETONCE)
    {
        WrapsLeft = Eaten - (Buy_SETONCE + TotalFreebie);
    }
    else
    {
        WrapsLeft = Eaten - Buy_SETONCE;
    }
```

So, effectively your code looks like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Introduce amount of wraps");
Wrap_SETONCE = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Introduce number of freebies per wrap");
Freebie_SETONCE = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Introduce amount of candy bought");
Buy_SETONCE = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

TotalFreebie = (Buy_SETONCE / Wrap_SETONCE) * Freebie_SETONCE;
Eaten = Buy_SETONCE + TotalFreebie;
WrapsLeft = Eaten - Buy_SETONCE;

if (Freebie_SETONCE > Buy_SETONCE || Freebie_SETONCE >= Wrap_SETONCE)
{
    Console.WriteLine("COMPANY GOES BANKRUPT");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    TotalFreebie = (Buy_SETONCE / Wrap_SETONCE) * Freebie_SETONCE;
    Eaten = Buy_SETONCE + TotalFreebie + (TotalFreebie / Wrap_SETONCE);

    if (TotalFreebie > Wrap_SETONCE)
    {
        WrapsLeft = Eaten - (Buy_SETONCE + TotalFreebie);
    }
    else
    {
        WrapsLeft = Eaten - Buy_SETONCE;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Eaten, WrapsLeft);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now the `if` that tests if the company goes bankrupt does not rely on the initial values of `TotalFreebie`, `Eaten`, & `WrapsLeft` variables, so you can move those calculations into the second half of the `if`.

But that leads to some unnecessary repetition.

Assuming that I can ignore the faulty `do` loop, I can end up writing your entire code like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Introduce amount of wraps");
int Wrap = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Introduce number of freebies per wrap");
int Freebie = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Introduce amount of candy bought");
int Buy = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (Freebie > Buy || Freebie >= Wrap)
{
    Console.WriteLine("COMPANY GOES BANKRUPT");
}
else
{
    int TotalFreebie = (Buy / Wrap) * Freebie;
    int Eaten = Buy + TotalFreebie + (TotalFreebie / Wrap);
    int WrapsLeft = Eaten - Buy - (TotalFreebie > Wrap ? TotalFreebie : 0);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Eaten, WrapsLeft);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: In fact this seems a lot more like the solution that our professor gave us, it makes more sense. Thanks!